# zsh: String with tab read from file is not equal to iteslf

Tags: shell, zsh

This has me completely stumped.
Basically, when I write a string to a file, and then read it back, the string does not equal itself.
How can I test that the string I read from the file is equal to the expected value?

Example:

```
➜ foo="foo\tbar"
➜ echo $foo > foo.txt
➜ bar=`head -n 1 foo.txt`

➜ printf $foo | od -x
0000000 6261 6463 6509 6766
0000010

➜ printf $bar | od -x
0000000 6261 6463 6509 6766
0000010

➜ [ $bar != $foo ] && echo "they are not equal ????"
they are not equal ????
```

It seems to me that the two variables are clearly equal.  Why is bash evaluating them as not equal?

If I run the above tests without the `\t` in the string, the equality works fine, so I thought the tab character has something to do with this.

However, if I set `$bar` directly to `$foo` (`$bar=$foo`) with the tab included, then the equality passes, so it can't be directly a result of there being a tab in the string.

What is going on here?  How can I ensure the first line of a file matches a string with tabs?

All tests are run with zsh.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Comment: Not a quoting issue; `zsh` doesn't perform word-splitting on parameter expansions.

Comment: If you aren't testing answers with bash, *don't tag for bash*. They're not mutually compatible shells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zsh`'s implementation of `echo` conforms to the POSIX standard, so the literal characters `\` and `t` in the value of `foo` are converted to a literal ASCII tab character when you write the value to `foo.txt`. `printf` also processes the `\t`. You can see that `foo` and `bar` are indeed different using `declare -p`:

```
% declare -p foo bar
typeset foo='foo\tbar'
typeset bar=$'foo\tbar'
```

or using `printf` properly:

```
192% printf '%s' $foo | od -x
0000000      6f66    5c6f    6274    7261
0000010
192% printf '%s' $bar | od -x
0000000      6f66    096f    6162    0072
0000007
```

You can also see that the lengths are different:

```
% echo ${#foo} ${#bar}
8 7
```

However, you probably wanted a literal tab in the value of `foo` in the first place:

```
% foo=$'foo\tbar'
% printf '%s' $foo | od -x
0000000      6f66    096f    6162    0072
0000007
```

Comment: Ahh, I see.  So foo is literally stored as "foo\tbar" (without a tab character).

Comment: For now, my solution is to set a "expected_foo" varialble like expected_foo=\`echo $foo\`, and then use that in my [ ... ] statement.    Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Yes, just use the `$'...'` quoting shown at the end of the answer.

Comment: Also, note that `echo "$foo"` in `bash` *probably* outputs a backslash and `t` separately, without replacing the with a literal tab. There are ways to make `bash`'s `echo` POSIX-compliant, but they are all off by default. For predictable results, always use `printf`.